# use CrawlSpider in scraping

Tags: python, scrapy

I try to do it with a CrawlSpider and this is the code but the spider didn't return a result (opened and closed after) :

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from torent.items import TorentItem

class MultiPagesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'job'
    allowed_domains = ['tanitjobs.com/']
    start_urls = ['http://tanitjobs.com/browse-by-category/Nurse/?searchId=1393459812.065&action=search&page=1&view=list',]
    rules = (
            Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('page=*',),restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pageNavigation"]',))
            , callback='parse_item', follow= True),
            )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items= hxs.select('//div[@class="offre"]/div[@class="detail"]')
        scraped_items =[]
        for item in items:
            scraped_item = TorentItem() 
            scraped_item["title"] = item.select('a/strong/text()').extract() 
            scraped_items.append(scraped_item)
        return items
```

Comment: use `allowed_domains = ['tanitjobs.com']` instead of `allowed_domains = ['tanitjobs.com/']`

Answer (score 0):

What @paul t. said in the comment above, but additionally you need to return `scraped_items` rather than `items` otherwise you'll get a large number of errors that look like this:

```
2014-02-26 23:40:59+0000 [job] ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem or None, got 'HtmlXPathSelector' in 
<GET http://tanitjobs.com/browse-by-category/Nurse/?action=search&page=3&searchId=1393459812.065&view=list>
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Please remember to accept and up vote the most appropriate answers to your questions.  :)